# How can you get redstone to not connect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

What I mean by this is that I'm trying to get redstone to not connect when placed beside each other. 
C=Connected redstone
D=Connected redstone

Whats happening:
CC
CC
CC
What I want to happen:
CD
CD
CD

In the examples, C and D are different lines of redstone that are connected if they are the same letter. So when I try this the redstone connects into a loop whereas I want two seperate lines of redstone.

Comment: Redstone dust always connects to all adjacent pieces of dust.

Comment: There are of course mods that allow that - would that be an acceptable answer?

Comment: @eibbor_gnik
Could you provide some images? Also, try to take these screenshot photos in high-intensity light, it'll help us to identify the problem.

Answer (score 4):

There may be a better solution to your specific red stone contraption you are building, but here are some solutions to get 2 Redstone signals side-by-side.

**Redstone dust & opaque blocks**
[image]
Pro: Has the fastest Redstone travel time
Con:Not directly side by side, have to use Repeaters every 15 blocks

**Repeaters**
[image]
Pro: side by side
Con: not fast, have to use Repeaters every 1 block

**Sticky Pistons and Redstone Blocks**
[image]
Pro:Side by side
Con:Not super slow, but not as fast a Redstone, expensive, makes noise

<s>If you really wanted side by side red stone, you could use commands or mc edit to create Redstone that doesn't connect, just don't update the block.</s> (EDIT: And by don't update the block, that includes no Redstone signals traveling through the Redstone: that updates the block.)

This was done in my red stone test world in Minecraft Pocket Edition, but all the Redstone mechanics shown here work on the PC version as well.

Comment: For the repeater method you can alternate redstone and repeaters in a checkerboard pattern to improve speed and cost.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this question right you would either have to have one line be repeaters, or on a block height different than the other line with a block separating them, both of those should keep the lines from connecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use more than one y-level, running wires on different levels with a block cutting the diagonal connection will keep them from connecting:

[image: Two redstone wires separated by blocks]

If you cannot use a second y-level, you will need to use components other than wire.  I've shown two examples below - the top one requires you to have an even number of torches (since they invert the signal) but is somewhat more resource-efficient over distances:

[image: Redstone torch-repeater line and repeater line]

If neither of these fulfills your need, you should update your question to include your specific issue.

Comment: In the future try not to have super dark screen shots. A torch or glowstone will fix that right up next time.